# What are the observable difference between Bhakti mantra and Beeja mantra?

Tags: mantras

I have been collecting some informations from the internet about mantras and came to a conclusion that they can be divided into two types. Beeja mantra and Bhakti mantra. Beeja mantras are the mantras which can produce bad effects if chanted without any initiation from a guru. On the other hand Bhakti mantras can be chanted by commoners and will produce no bad effects. How can anybody notice that a mantra is a beeja mantra or a Bhakti mantra? Does the presence of words like hrim,Kleem , krim, fat’,etc convey that the mantra is a beeja mantra and should not be chanted without initiation?

Comment: Yes, the presence of single-syllable aksharas - hrim, shrim, kleem, hum, etc make a mantra beeja mantra. It won't specifically harm someone but rather have no overall effect more than a bhakti mantra if not initiated. Bhakti mantras are like songs, stotra, praises, hymns that can be sung.